# Hide Column in Sharepoint List with coding

Tags: sharepoint

I need to hide SharePoint list columns? User should not see and modify columns hidden columns. How can I hide columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide column field in New/View/Edit Form by using JavaScript in Script Editor Web Part like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type=text/javascript></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('nobr:contains("your field name")').closest('tr').hide();
});
</script>
```

Reference:

[How to make a Column hidden in SP List Item View?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/222159/how-to-make-a-column-hidden-in-sp-list-item-view)

Answer (score 0):

This is done by creating views.

When you create a SharePoint list and are adding in different columns, etc. At the bottom you have the option to create views.  Create the view to only show the columns that you want them to see and then assign the view to the users you want.